# I am getting an error while using SqlFunctions.SoundCode and string.Spilit() together in C# EF

Tags: c#

I want to search using soundex() with each words of a sentence.

**My C# code is:**

```
 all_data = db.SearchEntities.Where(
   s => (s.EventTitlePrimaryLang
     .Split(' ')
     .ToArray()
     .Any(d => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(d.ToString()) == 
               SqlFunctions.SoundCode(srQuery.ToString())
   ))
   )
 //.AsEnumerable()
 //.AsQueryable()
   .ToList();
```

**Getting this error**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[]
>   ToArrayString'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: If you were writing this SQL directly, what SQL would you be trying to generate?

Comment: I see you are using a `.ToArray()` after your `.Split(' ')`. Does a split not already return an array?

Comment: `Split` already produces an array of strings, so `d` is  a `string`. No need to call `ToString` on `d` or `.ToArray`. What is `srQuery` defined as?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] - in particular we need to see how `srQuery` is declared and assigned.

Comment: Then you don't need to call `ToString` on it either, as it is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_data = db.SearchEntities.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.EventTitlePrimaryLang))
                            .ToList();

var filteredData = all_data.Where(s => (s.EventTitlePrimaryLang.Split(' ')
                                                               .Any(d => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(d)) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(srQuery)))
                           .ToList();
```

OR

```
all_data = db.SearchEntities.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.EventTitlePrimaryLang))
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(s => (s.EventTitlePrimaryLang.Split(' ')
                                                               .Any(d => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(d)) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(srQuery)))
                            .ToList();
```

As Pointed out by reckface in another answer.

OR

As another alternative to the above which may or may not work, you could opt to build the query using for loops.

```
    var results = db.SearchEntities.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.EventTitlePrimaryLang))
                                .AsQueryable();    

    foreach(var r in results) {
        var langSplit = s.EventTitlePrimaryLang.Split(' ');

        foreach(var val in langSplit) {
            results = from a in results
                    where SqlFunctions.SoundCode(val) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(srQuery)
                    select a;
        }
    }

    return results.ToList();
```

The above would then filter your results bit by bit.

EDIT:

Removed The redundant `.ToString()` calls

EDIT 2:

Edited the code example to better help fix the problem and Identify what is wrong.

The problem is that `Entity Framework` cannot convert `.Split(' ')` into valid `SQL` Code. As a work around, you will need to retrieve the data first, then filter that data using `LINQ`

EDIT 3:

Added possibly another way to solve the issue by using `.AsQueryable()` to filter down the results. Thus you don't need to query the database for a large dataset and filter the results, you could get the filtered results from the db directly, assuming it dosen't build the split into the database query. I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are attempting to filter on the split results of a property in your query. Everything in the `.Where()` clause off the `DbSet` called `SearchEntities` will need to be evaluated as SQL.

The error message is telling you that EF can't convert `x.MyProperty.Split()` into SQL.

The only alternative, which might not be desirable in this case is to have a more general filter, then perform the complex filtering in you materialised results.

```
db.SearchEntities.Where(s => Something general to narrow down your results)
             .AsEnumerable() // materialise your results
             .Where(s => s.EventTitlePrimaryLang
                          .Split(' ') 
                          .Any(d =>  something specific with your d and sQuery))
             .ToArray();
```